# WooCommerce after product gallery action

Tags: woocommerce

I am using this action to add additional info below product images:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_after_product_gallery_item', 
'fvp_woocommerce_admin_after_product_gallery_item', 10, 2 );
function fvp_woocommerce_admin_after_product_gallery_item( $thepostid, $attachment_id ){

    echo '<a href="#" class="fvp-edit-product-image" data-id="'.$attachment_id.'" 
title="Edit">Edit</a>';
}
```

[image]

This works well on page load, but when I go to "Add product gallery images" and select new image, this does not execute. Is there an action for that?